# Difference between using '=' and ':' when declaring class members in typescript

Tags: typescript

Sorry this might sound noobish. I am learning Angular, and working on the tutorial, i am trying to figure out the difference and the usage scenarios of ':' and '=' while declaring property

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes= HEROES;

  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void{
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not related to angular, its only related to the semantics of typescript and some basic programming language concepts

Answer (score 1):

`selectedHero: Hero` is declaring a variable with the type `Hero`, but the variable is `undefined`.

`heroes = HEROES` declares a variable with type `any` and assigns it to value `HEROES`.

The full assignment for TypeScript would be 
`varName: varType = varValue`

Comment: Thank you for quoting the TypeScript example.